# Car Gear Indicator

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, diodes, resistor-transistor-logic

I'm new in here and I'm very new to electronics and have a very little knowledge about it. I'm trying to do a project in where I have a car with manual gears 1,2,3 & 4. Each will be represented by a switch so altogether 4 switches. The switches are connected through a logic circuits and ended with a 7-segment LED.

When 1 is pressed, it displays "1" on the LED,
When 2 is pressed, it displays "2" on the LED,
When 3 is pressed, it displays "3" on the LED,
When 4 is pressed, it displays "4" on the LED,

*NOTE;
I need to represent the logic circuits as Diode-Transistor-Logic or Resistor-Transistor-Logic..
Can anyone here help me build the schematic for this project? I need it to pass my subject for my first year.. And I have very little knowledge on this stuffs.. And i'm in a hurry. So i got no choice but to seek for help! Thanks!

Comment: Sound like homework. We can help with homework, but we won't do it for you. What steps have you taken to solve the problem already? Show your work and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I have search the net for this kind of project, but they only used DIODES to make the circuit happen. And they have 5 inputs, which are 1 2 3 4 and Reverse (R).. A friend of mine suggested this to me, and design this circuit using transistors and diodes with DTL logic. My teacher didn't taught us how to make one of these, we're only on the basics of electronics.. So i don't know where to start.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do (clues): -

1. Decide whether to use a common anode or common cathode display
2. List what segments need to be fed current for each of the numbers 1 to 4
3. work out what value of resistor needs to be put in series with each segment
4. Think of a way to activate the requisite segments for a particular number without lighting  segments that are not needed (I'm thinking you need diodes - hint)
5. Produce 4 connections for the 4 "banks" of LEDs you will drive for each number
6. These four connections exclusively will drive only the LEDs needed
7. Connect the 4 connections to four switches.

I think you'll need 16 diodes and 7 resistors.

Answer (score 0):

When eg 4th gear is selected you want to display a 4.
The single input from 4th gear has to light the segments that make up a "4".
There are 4 of them (and 2 for a "1". 5 for a "2" and 5 for a "3"")

Name segments a b c d e f g clockwise starting at top bar and name middle = g .
You want segments b c f g lit to show a "4".

Look up DTL logic on eg Google.
You want 1 x 4 input DTL gate that gives an output ONLY when all 4 inputs are ON - ie an AND gate. Look up DTL "AND" and see how you use 4 diodes,  1 x transistor and 1 or 2 or 3 resistors to make the "gate".

Once you understand that, if you still have problems, explain what you know so far, ask questions and we will help.